# Windows System Idle Process - details on complex CPU power saving methods and other power-saving mechanisms

Tags: windows, cpu, power-management, cpu-usage, powersave

Wikipedia's article about [System Idle Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Idle_Process) states (emphasis mine):

> Later versions of Windows implement *more complex CPU power saving methods*. On these systems the idle thread will call routines in the Hardware Abstraction Layer to reduce CPU clock speed or to implement *other power-saving mechanisms*.

Where is to read the internal implementation details about these *more complex CPU power saving methods* and *other power-saving mechanisms*?